# Must the person be tied up by Wonder Woman's Lasso of Truth in order for it to work?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman

This is coming from someone not very familiar with Wonder Woman's canon, so I'm curious if any of it ever shows any cases of the Lasso of Truth working without the person being tied up in the standard way?  The "standard way" I've seen is the lasso around the torso, pinning their arms to their sides.  Can it work by merely touching the person, or perhaps by being tied around the person in a rather non-standard way, like around the ankle, for example?

Comment: https://external-preview.redd.it/yWoZUUFrHJJyTvp9x8QTbkpceh82ADZjjewayYb9fzA.jpg?width=1024&auto=webp&s=60fabd48b3741498844bf0fa56de8f7c1ed2946b

Comment: https://memestatic1.fjcdn.com/comments/Ltlt+it+depends+on+the+continuity+i+_c304923ea615c465f67a0ae386b6af84.jpg

Comment: https://comicnewbies.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/green-lantern-touched-the-lasso-of-truth.jpg

Comment: Touching it seems to be sufficient. I'll let someone with more knowledge of Justice League answer though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 2017 DCEU film *Wonder Woman* the person doesn’t need to be tied up but it appears to have to be tied around them to work. In the below video the first clip shows the classic bound body and arms but in the second it is just wrapped around the wrist.

In *Wonder Woman Annual 1* the Lasso of Truth works by Wonder Woman, Batman and Superman just by holding onto it.

[image: Wonder Woman approaches Batman and Superman and gets them to hold onto the Lasso]

Comment: In the Justice League Movie Aquaman is affected by just sitting on it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJDn5dgVVpM.

Comment: In the first animated DC Wonder Woman movie, Steve Trevor is effected when he doesn't notice he's touching it.